# FragmentTransaction add() method argument error

Tags: android, android-fragments

My code is a s follows-

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Enter.flame
{
private boolean mShowingBack = false;
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) 
    {

        Enter f1=new Enter();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        ft.add(R.id.container,f1);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
    else
        mShowingBack = (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);

}
```

The Enter class extends **Fragment**

The error I get is-
**The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Enter)**

But I don't get the error when using **getSupportFragmentManager()**. I Searched other similar questions here which said that the error occurs when using Both the Support Fragment Library and Normal Fragment Library at the same time, But I haven't done so here.

Comment: So, you are trying to implement a Class? Shouldn't it be an Interface instead? Could you please show your Enter code?

Comment: I am implementing an interface. It works great with **getSupportFragment()**, but the error only occurs with **getFragment()**.

Comment: That has to be related with your Enter Interface. Please show at least the declaration of that Class. Anyway. you should stick with getSupportFragmentManager(), since it will not affect your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I can literally see that you imported the support library here:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

So yes, you used the support library. And this is whats causing your error.
Either you use both support type of activity/fragments, or you use both of the "normal" versions. Dont mix and match them, that never ends well.

Comment: Didn't help. I removed the support library and Now my class extends **Activity** from **android.app.Activity** library. I have not imported any Support Library anymore. But still the problem persists!